# What the loading tag refers to?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Browsing the [loading](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loading), I find questions related to:

- loading and unloading payload
- load factor (upward accelerations)

I would like to clarify editing the description of the tag, but I'm unsure which one of the 2 meaning must be written down.

Comment: given the answers, I would suggest deletion of this tag.

Answer (score 8):

My feeling is that a [loading](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loading) tag isn't very useful because it's ambiguous, as your question says, and it's only used for 3 questions today anyway.

Instead, I'd suggest using [aircraft-limitations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-limitations) (or maybe [aircraft-performance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-performance)) for load factor and [ground-operations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-operations) for loading payload.

Comment: Does [tag:ground-operations] really cover that well though?  I think how a plane is loaded can effect how the plane flies, right?  Since it affects CG.  Calling it ground operations makes it sound like you are only talking about the physical act of moving cargo on and off the plane without regard to how it may effect balance and all the control surface issues that can follow from that..

Comment: @JayCarr Absolutely, and that's why we usually have multiple tags per question. In your example, I would probably add the weight-and-balance tag if that was the purpose of the question. Tagging isn't an exact science, it's just a 'good enough' way to categorize questions for people who are interested in certain topics.

Answer (score 3):

The [loading](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loading) tag has been declared bogus in its ambiguity, and beaten into nonexistence.

The three questions using it have been retagged into [aircraft-design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-design), [aircraft-limitations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-limitations), and [ground-operations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-operations) as appropriate.
Other potential uses of the "loading" tag also have more specific tags (e.g. [weight-and-balance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-and-balance)), so I don't think anyone will miss [loading](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loading).

Comment: Thus this tag should be deleted